# Why does Python turtle not exactly follow a grid?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I stumbled on this fact while working on a separate program I am writing, and am curious about why it happens and whether there is a way to stop it happening.

The code below is for a simple program to illustrate this. The turtle initially seems to follow a grid i.e. travels parallel to either the x or y-axis. This is shown by the first three of the turtles's printed coordinates. After two changes of direction the turtle seems to veer off from parallel to x or y-axis, as shown in subsequent coordinate printouts, even though the heading should always be a multiple of 90.

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
window = turtle.Screen()

    
def draw_square():
    for i in range(4):
        print("Coordinates of turtle: (", t.xcor(), ", ", t.ycor(), ")")
        t.forward(100)
        t.left(90)


def draw_line():
    for i in range(10):
        t.forward(20)
        print("Coordinates of turtle: (", t.xcor(), ", ", t.ycor(), ")")
    
draw_square()
draw_line()
```

Comment: it seems it keep position as float numbers and float can't keep every value so it keeps only aproximation - and this can make your problem like. It makes also problem in `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` which gives `False` instead of `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be just a floating-point precision error.

The differences you are seeing are really tiny, you can ignore them.

If you prefer seeing cleaner numbers, you can just round them to a few decimals (3 in this example) before printing them:

```
print("Coordinates of turtle: (", round(t.xcor(), 3), ", ", round(t.ycor(), 3), ")")
```